# Random effect and above cahnce performance in R

Tags: r, binary-data, glmm, accuracy

I am new to the world of GLMM, and I have a simple design. Each subject sees the same questions (4-choice). I want to treat the questions as random factor and test if subjects succeed above chance (0.25) in these questions. subjects are marked as Ss, Questions as Qs and accuracy (0/1) as ACC. In the past I used lme4. How can I test is ACC is above 0.25.
many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:
m1=lmer(data=d,Acc~1+(1|Stim)+(1|Ss))
conf1=confint(m1)

and verified that 0.25 is not in the confidance interval.
any other suggestions?